# Redmine: What could be wrong if secret_token is not used?

Tags: ruby, installation, redmine, secret-key, argument-error

I have installed Redmine. Not the first time but with machine something is different - and I don't know much about Ruby.

When I call the Redmine page I get the error in the browser:

> Internal error
>
> An error occurred on the page you were trying to access. If you
>   continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine
>   administrator for assistance.
>
> If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details
>   about the error.

In the log is this:

```
Started GET "/" for 80.120.10.114 at 2014-04-04 10:52:41 +0200

ArgumentError (A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb):
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:319:in `ensure_secret_secure'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:284:in `initialize'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:231:in `new'
...
```

But the file `secret_token.rb` exists. I have created it with

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake generate_secret_token
```

This file has the same owner and the same access rights as the other files. So I guess this causes not the problem.

What could it be?

Comment: try adding a `puts` or `log.info` line in the `secret_token.rb` file to make sure that it is read (on server load).

Comment: Indeed, it is no read. Putting some arbitrary charachters into this file didn't cause an error. So why isn't it used?

Comment: is it under `config/initializers`?

Comment: Yes. Like 00-core_plugins.rb, 10-patches.rb and so on.

Comment: I don't think so. But this may be since secret_token.rb is not used.

Comment: everything under `config/initializers` should run when the server is started: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration